# dnd-all-editions

Tags: discussion, tags

Brian suggested, as part of an answer to the D&D Next/5e dilemma, that [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) be changed to [dnd-all-editions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-all-editions), and [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) be used for 5e (since that’s how WotC’s branding it). That was quite unpopular, particularly since 6e will likely *also* be branded as Dungeons & Dragons without specifier, and then we have the same problem again.

But I think making [dnd-all-editions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-all-editions) and making [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) a synonym of it has a lot of merit. It means anyone who tries to tag their question [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) will have that change to [dnd-all-editions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-all-editions), immediately making it clear what the tag actually means, and potentially saving us some fixing. It’s also consistent with the rest of the D&D tags, which is nice.

Comment: And messes with our SEO in the bargain.

Comment: @mxyzplk Well, that's a matter of priority. To me, having the site work better and more intuitively is more important than SEO, but I suppose it might be a significant loss of SEO for a minor improvement in usability. I don't know enough SEO to say.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do not do this, it is counterintuitive (basically removes one of the most common terms ever from the tag space) and damaging to SEO.

Worse than the cons - there is no reason for it.  As mentioned in the other Q, 4e also brands itself as non versioned "D&D" and that has not been an issue.  Tag wikis and autocomplete and synonyms have resulted in a handful of mistags over years of RPG.SE operation.  There is currently no problem, and it is speculation that there will be a problem, and that speculation would have been equally valid for 4e and did not turn out that way. So I decline if and until this is a real problem manifesting on our site.

Answer (score -4):

Realized that without an answer to vote on, this isn't really going anywhere.

Anyway, proposal: migrate [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) questions to [dnd-all-editions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-all-editions), make [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) a synonym of [dnd-all-editions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-all-editions).

Potential problems:

- It messes with the site’s SEO; `dungeons` and `dragons` are more significant search terms than `dnd`
- [dungeons-and-dragons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) questions aren’t *necessarily* about *all* editions; it’s about Dungeons & Dragons in general, or across multiple editions, but it wouldn’t be unreasonable to tag a question specifically about TSR’s D&D or specifically WotC’s D&D with it, and [dnd-all-editions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-all-editions) might seem to contradict that practice.

Comment: That last one is a big deal to me: that makes this a major semantic change to the tag.